# Combining XAML/C# with html and WinJS

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, xaml, uwp, winjs

I want to build a UWP app with html and winJS, because with html you can use any open source library for brilliant UI like Bootstrap and Material Design, but I need to use some controls which are only present in XAML/C# format, for example media element of xaml, because video element of html5 doesn't support much formats.

So my question is how can I combine these two in one app? what is most clean and performant way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So my question is how can I combine these two in one app? what is most clean and performant way to do this?

The better way of combining these two in one app is using WebView within "XAML/C#" uwp project. But the web context could not invoke method in the local context. The only way for communication between WebView and local context is to use [`invokescript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_WebView_InvokeScriptAsync_System_String_Windows_Foundation_Collections_IIterable_System_String__) and [`window.external.notify`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview#properties_) method.